# Java Spring MVC & Jackson: get only selected variables from entities

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I have three entities `Hello`, `World` (and `Abc`):

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
@Entity
@Table(name="hello")
public class Hello implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private Integer address; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="world_id", nullable=false)
    private World world;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="abc")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Abc> abc;    
}

@Entity
@Table(name="world")
public class World implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="world")
    private List<Hello> hello;    
}
```

in Spring controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/json/world/get/all", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<World> getWorlds() {
    return worldManager.findAll();
}
```

If I go to mapped URL I get similar JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "address":123456,
      "world":{  
         "id":1,
         "address":"192.168.200.1"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "address":123457,
      "world":{  
         "id":1,
         "address":"192.168.200.1"
      }
   },
...
   }
]
```

`List<Abc>` is not in JSON - it is ok, but it has `@JsonIgnore`. But I do not want `world` objectcs in `hello` output in **this controller URL**, on another URL I need `hello` with `world`.

How can I do that? Something like dynamically adding/deleting anotation.

I tried Jackson views but it doesn't work - I do it bad :-(

How can I write two method in controller - one will return `hello` with all `world` objects and second method will return only `hello` without all `world` objects?

Comment: What persistence framework are you using?  You could set your relationships to lazy-load, and simply not fetch child objects when making requests to particular controller methods.

Comment: Hibernate and MySQL. Thank you I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson has an annotation called @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) at the class level.  This annotation means that Jackson will not output anything if the variable is null.  In your controller you could set the values you do not want to do send to null right before the return.  Something like this:

Modify Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="world")
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL) //New Line!!!
public class World implements Serializable {
...
...
}
```

have your two controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/json/world/get/all", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<World> getWorlds() {
    return worldManager.findAll();
}


@RequestMapping(value="/json/world/get/all2", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<World> getWorldsWithOutHellos() {
    List<World> result = worldManager.findAll();
    for (World world:result){
       world.setHello(null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: After I modify `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)` to `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` it works great. Thank you!